# Cannot federate the server at this time. 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-portal

When I go to federate the ArcGIS Server I get the following error message:

> "Unable to federate at this time"

When I look into both the Portal and AGS logs I get the same error message:

> "Failed to update the security configuration. Cannot update the
>   security configuration as server is not registered with Portal".

When I set the AGS logs to DEBUG I get this message:

> " Testing to see if this server has been registered with Portal as a
>   federated server. Failed to test if the server is registered with
>   Portal"

Then it states: "File or directory not found" in relation to http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml and this of course cannot be accessed as it is a completely disconnected environment.

I have also checked the following at 10.3.1:

- I was able to add store credentials of a secured ArcGIS Server service from the AGS I am trying to federate against so that proves that the certificates work as expected.
- ROOTs and INTERMEDIATEs have been imported into the Portal Java keystore.

The main confusion stems from the fact it was federated earlier this morning, the URLs I used were similar to these (with the actual names removed for security reasons)

SERVICES URL: `https://machinename.domain/arcgis`

ADMIN URL:    `https://machinename.domain:6443/arcgis`

The correct PSA details were used in the username and password.